# Why does grep match lazily when invoked with -zoP and matching backreference followed by newline?

Tags: regex, grep, posix, pcre

I have a file `cases`:

```
foo
bar
  cases:
    1: foo
    2: bar
baz
  cases:
    3: baz
quux
```

As the indentation always goes back again after the cases I want to list the cases with `grep -zoP '(\s*)cases:\n(\1.*\n)*' cases`, but that outputs

```
  cases:

  cases:
```

Whereas if I use `grep -zoP '(\s*)cases:\n(\1.*\n){1,}' cases`, I get the output I want:

```
  cases:
    1: foo
    2: bar
  cases:
    3: baz
```

This behavior doesn't appear with any similar regexp I've tried:

```
$ grep -o '\(foo\)bar\(\1\)*'<<<$'foobarfoofoofoofoo'
foobarfoofoofoofoo
$ grep -o '\(foo\)bar\(\1\)*'<<<$'foobarfoofoofoofoobax'
foobarfoofoofoofoo
$ grep -oP '(foo)bar(\1)*'<<<$'foobarfoofoofoofoobax'
foobarfoofoofoofoo
$ grep -zoP '(foo)bar(\1)*'<<<$'foobarfoofoofoofoobax'
foobarfoofoofoofoo
$ grep -zoP '(foo)\n*bar'<<<$'foo\n\n\n\n\n'
foo







$
```

Why does grep prefer to match my regexp 0 times?

Comment: Is that last example right? I also get the `bar` at the end of it. Also, your last sentence seems to be cut off.

Comment: @BenjaminW.Thanks for pointing that out, fixed it.

Comment: I think the problem is `\1` since the backreference enforces to match the exact same characters, which fails if there is a different number of spaces, i.e. `grep -zoP '(\s*)cases:\n(\s.*\n)*' cases`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought it was a bug, but I was pointed out that `\s`, which is a synonym for the POSIX character class `[:space:]` corresponds to `[ \t\n\r\f\v]` in the C locale and therefore also matches the preceding newline here.